# Futuristic vr game manhwa-manhua of a rich guy

Tags: story-identification, manga

I remember reading about a kind of manhua-manhwa where this MC invested all his money (he was from a rich family) into a vr game because he knew (I don't remember if it was reincarnated or just a dream) that the game was going to be a global success, thus getting the highest gears on the game and leveling up a lot, this happens on the first 3 or 5 chapters